# Apigee X KVM entries and TLS Keystore certificates Logs in Log Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, apigee

I have a project that need to query Logs for Apigee X using Log Explorer

I was able to query other Apigee objects such as apps and its credentials, api products etc. using this query

**resource.type="audited_resource"
resource.labels.service="apigee.googleapis.com"**

however in the case of KVM entries and TLS Keystore certificates log explorer do not show any record of its changes, although for the creation and deletion of KVM and TLS Keystore are showing, still we need the logs for the entries and the certificates. is there any way to get those logs in log explorer?

Any help is appreciated thanks